# Laravel order pivot relationship by its own relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a query that is currently:

```
Team::with('users')->services()->find($id);
```

The services scope is:

```
public function scopeServices($query)
{
    $query = $query;

    $query->with(['users.services' => function($q) {
        $q->whereHas('service', function($q) {
            $q->where('active', 1);
        })->with('service');
    }]);

    return $query;
}
```

This returns all the services per user of that team. The database tables are:

```
teams, users, service_user, services
```

Everything the query currently does it fine. But on my services table each row has an order field (int). Is it possible to return back the services in the order using the order field?

So in my view:

```
$team->user[0]->services
```

That will return the services in order of the field?